# Can I use 18AWG wire instead of 22AWG when doing guitar pedal modifications?

Tags: soldering, wire, guitar-pedal, gauge

I'm planning on doing some modifications to my Dunlop GCB95 Cry Baby wah pedal. As far as I can tell, the hookup wire in the pedal is 22AWG (it's difficult to read what's printed on the side). The smallest gauge of hookup wire my local hardware store had was 18AWG, and I decided to buy lengths of 3ft. in a few different colors. My thought process was that I should be able to use any hookup wire that is 22AWG or bigger. However, before I do anything to the pedal, I want to be sure that I won't run into any issues. Would it be okay to use the 18AWG wire, or do I need to get 22AWG wire?

Comment: at these frequencies and power levels that's perfectly fine.

Comment: The general rule of thumb in electronics is that it's always OK to use thicker copper wire. It's when you go towards a thinner one that you need to be careful. Then things like current/heat, voltage drop, signal loss etc etc may have to be considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very few circuits are designed in such a way as to require a *minimum* resistance or inductance of the interconnecting wire.  Audio folks sometimes do some odd things, but probably not that.  So while we can't technically know without examining the specific usage, electrically this will probably be fine.

The more practical issues you might run into would be related to the larger size and stiffness in getting things in place, and the greater heat perhaps needed when soldering (which might flow to connected things causing collateral damage to insulation, plastics, etc).  In some cases a larger wire might create a mechanical strain leading to future breakage of a solder join or component, but that can be as much about the details of installation as the actual wire size.

Also consider the relative merits of solid and stranded wire - the latter often being preferred.

Ultimately the actual greatest challenges would probably be related to any inexperience in doing such work.  If this audio gear is valuable, exercise extreme care, as it's quite easy to accidentally damage adjacent areas.   Doing one's own work is of course a noble path, but sometimes it makes sense to get some initial practice on more "throwaway" items.

Sometimes you can scrounge suitable project wire out of things being disposed, too.  Though beware that some cables use specialized wire types which aren't useful for general hookup, for example they may have strands twisted with a string, or be thin ribbons wound around one.  But if it has the *hand* of a nice interconnect wire, and on stripping appears to be just copper conductor, and takes solder without the insulation making too much of an acrid mess, it can be great.

Comment: You provided a detailed and thought-out answer that addresses everything I was wondering about and then some.  Thanks for that.  I went ahead and marked your answer as correct!

Answer (score 1):

Thicker wire - higher ampacity rating and lower resistance. Electrically it is ok to use 18AWG instead of 22AWG.

Comment: ...as long as the insulation is rated for the application voltage.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I forsee is that the 18AWG wire may make it slightly more difficult to make a neat/pretty job.

'Hookup wire' is 'hookup wire' ! Most certainly in a guitar effects pedal.